# Questions regarding xrandr

Tags: display-resolution, xrandr, source-code, gpu-driver, randr

1. I'm interested in looking into the `xrandr` source code.
   I googled `xrandr source code`, and found [this](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/X11apps/X11apps-44/xrandr/xrandr-1.3.4/xrandr.c) code from Apple's opensource site. Is that all of it?
   I don't think so, because one comment says:

> Thanks to Jim Gettys who wrote most of the client side code, and part of the server code for randr.

Where can I find the entire source-code?

2. The [Gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Xrandr) makes a point regarding xrandr:

> Adding the mode manually does not make the monitor work in the mode if it did not work before.

So this means there's no problem with `RandR`? The problem is with monitor and GPU support?

Comment: I don't get your second question, you can manually add a new mode to xrandr, I have 1080p laptop, everything is tiny, so I added a mode for 1366x768 (16:9) and it works perfect. Are you asking how to add a mode?

Comment: @markkirby did you add the mode manually, or did you just set it using xrandr?

Comment: I had to add a new mode, the laptop did not have a 1366x768 mode in display settings, just some strange stretched 16:10 options, so I made one. I think I used this guide https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions

Comment: @markkirby hmm... not sure what's going on **=(**

Comment: I think that link is referring to completely unsupported modes ie You can't add a 1080p mode to a 720p laptop. It is a strange point for them to make after showing how to set a mode.

Comment: @DevRobot , Otherwise if you are looking for upstream project (last updated source code) see http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get any source code from the repository’s, first open `software and updates` and check `source code`

[image]

Now you can use the `source` parameter in `apt` to pull any source right from the repos, `xrandr` is part of `x11-xserver-utils`, so use this command

```
apt-get source x11-xserver-utils
```